# How to find the vector perpendicular to a line and passes through a point

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find the vector perpendicular to a line that passes through a point that does not lie on that line?

Comment: which dimension? how does a vector pass through a line? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144554/find-the-equation-of-a-line-which-is-perpendicular-to-a-given-vector-and-passing?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec x=\vec a+\lambda\vec u$ be the equation of the line and $\vec p$ be any vector.  Then the orthogonal projection of $\vec p-\vec a$ along $\vec u$ is $\dfrac{\langle \vec p-\vec a,\vec u\rangle}{\|u\|^2}\vec u$.  Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

Build a vector perpendicular to the line first. 
Then build a line with direction of the just built vector and with the originally given point laying on the line

Comment: The question was derived from a field theory text book. The problem was to find the electric field at a point (1,5,2) due to an infinite line of charge placed on the x axis. The electric field at the point would be along the line perpendicular to the line of charge and passing through the point (1,5,2). Therefore I needed the vector perpendicular to the x axis and passing through the point (1,5,2).

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest the following: 
Consider $(1,0,0)$ as the normal vector of a surface.
Determine the surface with that normal vector through point $(1,5,2)$. Intersect this surface with your line (x-axis) and find the point p. Connection of p and (1,5,2) is your vector.

Comment: Please comment if any of this helped you and mark the answer which fits best, so your question doesn't remain in an unanswered state.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

In the $2$nd dimension, the line perpendicular to a line $ax+by+c=0$ and passes through a point $(x_1,y_1)$ can be reprensented as
$$b(x-x_1)-a(y-y_1)=0.$$